# How to change flat surface regression into curved surface in r?

Tags: r, plot, regression, curve, scatter

I'm trying to change flat surface to curved surface but it's difficult.

Looking at the scatter plot, the surface should be curved rather than flat. How can I modify my code?

Code and picture are below.

I'm so sorry that can't attach because of the large number of data files. I think the lm function probably creates that plane. Have an idea?

Thank you!

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(plot3D)
library(readxl)

RoomA <- read_excel("Data_without_outlier_RoomA.xlsx")


# x, y, z variables
x <- RoomA$Ammonia
y <- RoomA$Ventilation
z <- RoomA$Emissions

# Compute the linear regression (z = ax + by + d)
fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)
# predict values on regular xy grid
grid.lines = 25
x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = grid.lines)
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = grid.lines)
xy <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, y = y.pred)
z.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xy), 
                 nrow = grid.lines, ncol = grid.lines)
# fitted points for droplines to surface
fitpoints <- predict(fit)
# scatter plot with regression plane
scatter3D(x, y, z, pch = 20, cex = 1.5,
          theta = 320, phi = 25, ticktype = "detailed",
          xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "",  
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets = NA), main = "Room A")
```

[image]

Comment: Probably best to use something like `library(mgcv); fit <- gam(Emissions ~ te(Ammonia, Ventilation), data = RoomA)` unless you have a parametric model from science (which probably exists).

Comment: __EDIT :__ My bad this doesn't work : `lm(z ~ x**2 + y**2 + x:y)` . That would have been awesome if possible but you need to use surrogate variables to do so :
`mtcars$cyl_2 <- mtcars$cyl**2 ;
mtcars$disp_2 <- mtcars$disp**2 ;

fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl_2 + disp_2 + cyl:disp, data = mtcars) ;
summary(fit) ; `

Comment: @cbo No, you don't: `lm(z ~ poly(x, y, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))` But I wouldn't recommend fitting arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much @Roland, I have learnt something new and relearnt the formula interface. That way is definitely better and I was wrong (again) in the formula. The equivalent formula of `poly(x, y, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)` would be : `x_2 + y_2 + x*y` (with x_2, resp y_2,  the square vector of x, resp y).